# output is not what expected

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>


using namespace std;



int swapper(int n[],int s
)
{
for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    int temp=n[i];
    n[i]=n[i+1];
    n[i+1]=temp;
}
cout<<"\n Array Swapped !!!";
for (int i=0;1<s;i++)
{

    cout<<n[i]<<"\t";
}
return 0;
  }


int main()

 { 
 int n[20]; int s;

cout<<"\n enter array size:";

cin>>s;
cout<<"enter no in array according to size given";

for(int j=0;j<s;j++)

    {

        cin>>n[j];

    }

 swapper(n,s);

 return 0;

 getch();

 }
```

the output to this program does not swap the array elements,
instead it starts producing numbers in plenty
the entire code is written here
all other suggested changes have been made

the function is supposed to take in an integer array and its size as parameters and display an array with its adjacent elements swapped.

Comment: Just remove the `[]`. It's a syntax. No big science. Variable is called `n`, so you pass `n` to the function, not `n[]`.

Comment: did that, now a new problem, but cant explain, output is going wacky

Comment: @ArjunSukumaran Oh boy, sigh! That's not how the site works. We're not going to nanny you through all of your personal problems. Please check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call

```
swapper(n[],s);
```

is not right. Assuming the first argument of `swapper` is a `int*`, it needs to be:

```
swapper(n,s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[]` in your swapper function.